# Android + iOS - Install + Run / Run an app from a WWW link with specified parameters

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play, app-store

I am looking into possible solutions to install and run (or just run, if the app is already installed) an app with specific command line arguments that are provided from a www link.

**So the story goes as follows:**

1. A user clicks on a www link on his mobile device.
2. If the application is not installed, it opens the store on the app install page. User installs the app.
3. The application opens with specific command line arguments that were provided in the www link.

What I want to achieve, is a system for sharing specific content within the app and have automatic navigation to that item. Similar functionality is available with native notifications (when I press them, a specific content is opened in the app). I am using Unity 3D as the engine in case that matters.

**My question is, is it possible to do that? If it is, could you point me to some resources regarding the issue?**

Best regards,

Dzik

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is *Deep Linking*. I don't think you can inject any command line arguments (I could be wrong). I hope this link answers your question:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will have a look into it. I will upvote once I've verified that that's in fact what I was looking for! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for help. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Linking** is possible:
- [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) on Android
- [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) on iOS

In both cases it must be implemented natively in the iOS and Android-Project that you export from Unity.

**Command line arguments** are not possible natively, but you can just forward the data from the iOS/Android links to Unity. See [Unitys manual on plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) for setting up the communication.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will have a look into it. I will upvote once I've verified that that's in fact what I was looking for! Cheers!

Comment: @Dzik: If the links helped you please accept the answer and upvote, if possible.